# Send email to specific users using webforms

Tags: drupal-webform

In a view, everytime a user clicks on a link "click to connect" field, an email has to be sent to the specific username based on its id. I am using webform to send the mail. But, it restricts me to send all mails to the same email address. In order to hide the email to which mail has to be sent, I am fetching the id of the user(to whom mail has to be sent) in a hidden field in webform. But, i can't figure out a way to get the destination email dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do the trick

http://drupal.org/project/webform_bonus